# Solution solving Emulator screen?

Tags: android

I have recently downloaded android studio and whenever i create my virtual device it shows completely blank and it doesn't boot up or something like that enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to update emulator from sdk manager and update graphic card driver

also you can try this:
when creating new emulator (or you can edit a created emulator) go to:

advanced > Emulated Performance > Graphics

and change it to: software